Apache mod_cache mod_cache_disk with shared persistent volume
We use Apache in Kubernetes and recently enabled mod_cache_disk. Each pod is using a local directory.
Will it work if I point the cache directory to a ReadWriteMany (RWX) Persistent Volume
so all pods share the disk cache? and what about CacheLockPath ?
I am worried about potential cache corruption.
Thanks!!
